# Is there a way to read Git tags with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs, git-tag

I'm going to start tagging a codebase using Git tags, but I would also like to display this tag somewhere within my app, so that the testers know which version they are testing.

Is there a way to read what the current Git tag using JavaScript?

FYI, I use Grunt.js to build the app. However, a vanilla JS solution would preferable.

Comment: I would be surprised if this was possible. JavaScript is purely client side and the git tags are present on the server. The client has no concept of git.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, maybe there is a way to read it using a Grunt.js package in my build scripts.

Comment: Oh it's completely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `git-rev-sync` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-rev-sync), you can create a custom task to retrieve the current tag and store it as a `grunt.option` to use elsewhere in your grunt tasks:

```
var git = require('git-rev-sync');

function currentGitTag() {
    var currentTag = git.tag();
    grunt.option('tag', currentTag);
}

grunt.registerTask('gitTag', currentGitTag);
```

To access the value within grunt: `grunt.option('tag');`.

You can also access the value via template strings: `<%= grunt.option('tag') %>`

Answer (score 2):

[isomorphic-git](https://isomorphic-git.org/) has a [listTags()](https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/listTags) function that does just that. The package is available as a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-git). Example snippet copied from the API documentation:

```
let tags = await git.listTags({ dir: '.' })
console.log(tags)
```

Currently, isomorphic-git does not support creating tags (at the time of writing, the latest release of the package is version 0.37.3). However, there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git/issues/15) implying that the work has been started and it will be added in the future.

Comment: As of Feb. 2023 it supports creating tags.